# Unable to upgrade dell vostro 3558 laptop to ubuntu 16.04LTS from 14.04LTS properly

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, shutdown, dell-vostro

I recently upgraded my laptop (Dell Vostro 3558, with Ubuntu 14.04 inbuilt) to Ubuntu 16.04, but it was not working properly. When I upgraded it, a notification said that the system may be unstable. I was not able to shutdown my laptop(when I tried to do that i.e clicked the shutdown button, nothing happened). I somehow managed to shut it down, by removing the battery, but then it didn't start(boot again). There was just the **purple screen** and the LED on **Capslock** key kept **blinking**. Nothing happened. What should I do, should I restore my system back to factory mode(as there is an option of it just before the booting starts) or what should I do to successfully use the upgraded version?

Comment: Use a _live cd_ and run `sudo fdisk -l` and post out out

Comment: If you boot from 16.04 live media, does that work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another computer, make a live USB with Ubuntu or another Linux, boot on it, go to the partition where your current Ubuntu is and **backup your data** .

You can try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from that Live USB and see if it fix your problem. If that doesn't fix it and you don't get a better answer, just install a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 as I guess that the factory reset will just get you back to a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yes I get fresh Ubuntu 14.04 by restoring, but I did upgradation twice but still the same problem persists

Answer (score 0):

You will be better of by just doing a fresh install of ubuntu in the long run, to avoid future issues with the system.do a fresh install, if it resloves your issue, it was a system failure, although "*There was just the purple screen and the LED on Capslock key kept blinking. Nothing happened*"
might just be a a defect in your physical drive, but i doubt it.

Comment: I did the install twice but the same problem persists.